# Making emboss buttons

Tags: html, css

```
height: 160px;
width: 160px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: capitalize;

-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;

border-width: 0px;
border-radius: 20px;

box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
inset 0 2px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);

margin: 15px 5px;

background: linear-gradient(top, #23b224, #23b224);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #23b224, #23b224);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #23b224, #23b224);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #23b224), color-stop(100%, #23b224));
```

The code above will produce the following result:

[image]

But what I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

I want my buttons to appear like the buttons in the second picture. How to do it?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Also could you post a larger second image?

Comment: As you can see, the button in the second image is more emboss than the 1st image. The button in the first image looks like flat!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, also could you find a larger second image? Maybe play around with a CSS3 button generator until you get to the result you're looking for - http://css3buttongenerator.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and let me know....

```css
input {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 6px 12px lightgreen, inset -1px -10px 5px darkgreen, 1px 2px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 6px 12px lightgreen, inset -1px -10px 5px darkgreen, 1px 2px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 6px 12px lightgreen, inset -1px -10px 5px darkgreen, 1px 2px 1px black;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<input type=button>
```

Reference:-https://dev.opera.com/articles/beautiful-ui-styling-with-css3/

Comment: Try this let me know about it.

Comment: It didnt worked for me.     :(

Comment: Why? let me know what is the problem...

Comment: It appears flat to me, not emboss.

Comment: ok let me give you another example...ok

Comment: Now see it will help you...ok

Answer (score 2):

This is the demo with code

Click Here for [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9g6qpyg/)

This is Full Code with Css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
.modern {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background: #B8ED01;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5),
    0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  /* Font styles */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.modern:hover  { background: #C7FE0A; }
.embossed-link {
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 3px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.22), 
    inset 0 -3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.17), 
    inset 0 20px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.12), 
    0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 
    0 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.modern.embossed-link {
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5),
    0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    inset 0 3px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.22), 
    inset 0 -3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 
    inset 0 20px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.12), 
    0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 
    0 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.modern.embossed-link:active {
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.socle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.socle:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 
inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  top: -6px; bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px; left: -6px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="example-wrapper clearfix">
    <h3>Button Styles</h3>
    <div class="demo-wrapper">
        <a class="modern" href="#">Modern</a>
        <a class="modern embossed-link" href="#">Modern embossed</a>
        <a class="modern socle" href="#">Modern with socle</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```